# Pushing Android source tree to a private Git repository

Tags: android, git, android-source, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm trying to push Android source tree to a private Git repository.

Following the instructions from [official documentation](https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading) for Android, I have initialized a Repo client using `repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest` and I downloaded the Android source tree using `repo sync`.

The resulting directory is 73GB in size, which includes 43GB `.repo` directory.

I want to push this entire directory to a private Git repository, but some of the files are too big which prevents me from doing the usual git push.

I'm aware that Git LFS exists, but I'm not sure how I would go about tracking all the big files in a source tree of this size.

What would be the best approach to this problem?